# How to get CSS on-off button value in PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Well,

I have this code which generate CSS on-off button in a php while loop:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch<?php echo $i ?>" <?php echo $status; ?>>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

When the on-off button changes then I am calling a PHP page using jQuery/Ajax.

**jQuery/Ajax Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onoffswitch").change(function() {

      var hiddenID = $(this).find("[name='hiddenID']").val()
      var status = $('.onoffswitch-checkbox').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'changeInlineData.php',
        data: {
          'id' : hiddenID,
          'status' : status,
        },
        dataType : 'html',        
        success: function ( result ) {
          $('.validation_msg').html(result);           
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Here you can see I just pass 2 key which is `id` and `status` in a php page. Now in php page I see the `id` value only not `status` value. Everytime `status` key is showing 0. It's should be 0 or 1.

**PHP page:**

```
<?php
echo $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
echo $status = (int) $_POST['status'];
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I see in console log network tab that is showing status:on always if I toggle the button to on or off!!

Form Data
id:2203
status:on

Comment: can you check if the console shows the value of `var status` correctly when changed the button state?

Comment: @ShobiPP every time it's showing status:on if I toggle the button to on or off.

Comment: the checkbox doesn't have a value attribute

Answer (score 1):

You have to take value of checked checkbox. Change your status var in jquery as below :

```
var status = $('.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked').val();
```

Comment: HI there, Now I am checking t his: `var status = $('.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked').val();     alert(status);`

Comment: If its on then alert is showing on but if it's going to off then showing undefined.